# How do I properly implement a sqrt operator into a command line calculator?

Tags: java, for-loop, math, intellij-idea, calculator

I am running a command line Calculator that should take user input and solve it, then output the answer. i.e input: "2+5*sqrt 9" output: 17 or input: "6x2^3-3" output: 45. This is what I have:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 0;
        String[] operators = {"^", "/", "*", "+", "-"};
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputs = myScan.nextLine();
        ArrayList<Float> nums = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> ops = new ArrayList<>();

        float currentNum;
        int point = 0;
        //System.out.println(nums);
        String input = "";
        for (int p = 0; p < inputs.length() - 4; p++) {
            if (inputs.startsWith("sqrt", p)) {
                input += inputs.substring(point, p) + inputs.charAt(p + 5) + "^0.5";
                System.out.println(input);
                point = p + 6;
            }
        }
        input += inputs.substring(point);
        System.out.println(input);
        //System.out.println(inputs);
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i)) && i != input.length() - 1) {
                try {

                    if (input.charAt(i) == '.') {
                        int j = i;
                        while (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(j + 1))) {
                            j++;
                            counter++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        //System.out.println(input.substring(point, i));
                        currentNum = Float.parseFloat(input.substring(point, i));
                        point = i + 1;
                        nums.add(currentNum);
                    }
                    for (String op : operators) {
                        if (input.startsWith(op, i)) {
                            ops.add(op);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Not valid" + input.substring(point, i));
                }
            } else if (i == input.length() - 1) {
                try {
                    currentNum = Float.parseFloat(input.substring(point));
                    nums.add(currentNum);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error" + input.substring(point));
                }
            }
        }
        nums.add(Float.parseFloat(input.substring(point)));

        // Evaluate the expression using the order of operations
        for (String operator : operators) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ops.size(); j++) {
                String op = ops.get(j);
                if (op.equals(operator)) {
                    float num1 = nums.get(j);
                    float num2 = nums.get(j + 1);
                    float result = switch (op) {
                        case "^" -> (float) Math.pow(num1, num2);
                        case "/" -> num1 / num2;
                        case "*" -> num1 * num2;
                        case "+" -> num1 + num2;
                        case "-" -> num1 - num2;
                        default -> 0;
                    };

                    nums.set(j, result);
                    nums.remove(j + 1);
                    ops.remove(j);
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }
        float answer = nums.get(0);
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

When the problem does not include square root, the calculator runs fine, but when it is present this error is thrown:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: Range [6, 1) out of      bounds for length 5
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:55)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$1.apply(Preconditions.java:52)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:213)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions$4.apply(Preconditions.java:210)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:98)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckFromToIndex(Preconditions.java:112)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkFromToIndex(Preconditions.java:349)
at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:4602)
at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2715)
at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:48)
```

My method of handling square roots is to convert "sqrt" to x^0.5 so that it runs smoothly. This works and the proper string is made but the error is thrown. Any Help?

Comment: Step through your program with the debugger.

Comment: So, which is line 48 in your code? The stack trace says it was a call to substring on line 48 that triggered the error.  The error message says you tried to call `.substring` on a `String` Object, requesting the substring that begins at index 6, ends at index 0, on a string that had a length of 5.  If you wonder why the error message has `[6,1)` instead of `[6,1]` or `(6,1)`, or if you wonder why I wrote "begins at 6, ends at index 0", take a look at the [String.substring (int, int)[() API.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Line 48 is my catch exception. I don't understand why that would cause the error. This is it: } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Not valid" + input.substring(point, i));
                }

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Wait I've seen it. I did not re set the point variable to 0 before the second loop so it would be out of bounds. I appreciate the help on identifying the error.